Proof that space of random variables is complete
I'm trying to prove that $d(X,Y) = E\left ( \frac{|X-Y|}{1+|X-Y|}\right)$ is a metric on the space of random variables, that $d(X_n,X) \rightarrow 0$ if and only if $X_n \rightarrow X$ in probability, and that the space of random variables is complete with respect to $d(\, \cdot \, , \cdot\, )$.
I have proven the first two parts, namely that $d(\, \cdot \, , \cdot\, )$ is a metric and that it induces the topology of convergence in probability. For the last part, which states that the space of random variables is complete with respect to $d(\, \cdot \, , \cdot\, )$,  I have the following attempt at a proof, and I would like to know if there are any issues with it:
proof: First we deal with the case where $X_n \geq 0$. Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be the probability space and let $X_n$ be a cauchy sequence with respect to $d(\, \cdot \, , \cdot\, )$. Define $Y_n(\omega) = \inf_{k\geq n}X_k(\omega)$, and
\begin{equation}
X_{\infty}(\omega) = \lim\inf_{n\rightarrow \infty} X_n (\omega) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}Y_n(\omega),
\end{equation}
for all $\omega \in \Omega$. Then the $Y_n$ and $X_\infty$ are random variables, since they are measurable, and $Y_n \uparrow X_\infty$. Since $(X_n)$ is Cauchy, $d(X_n,Y_n) \rightarrow 0$, and moreover $d(X_\infty, Y_n) \rightarrow 0$ by an application of the monotone convergence theorem, so we can conclude that
\begin{align}
d(X_\infty,X_n) \leq d(X_\infty, Y_n) + d(X_n,Y_n) \rightarrow 0, 
\end{align}
hence $X_n \overset{d}{\rightarrow} X_\infty$. For a general sequence $X_n$, write $X_n = X^+_n - X^-_n$ and define $Y_n^\pm$ and $X_\infty^\pm$ as above. Then
\begin{align}
d(X_\infty^+-X_\infty^-,X_n^+-X_n^-) &\leq d(X_n^+-X_n^-,Y_n^+-Y_n^-) + d(X_\infty^+-X_\infty^-,Y_n^+ - Y_n^-) \\ 
&\leq d(X_\infty^+-X_\infty^-,Y_n^+-X_\infty^-)+d(Y_n^+-Y_n^-,Y_n^+-X_\infty^-)\\&\quad\quad +d(X_n^+-X_n^-,Y_n^+ - Y_n^-) \\
&= d(X_\infty^+, Y_n^+) + d(Y_n^-,X_\infty^-) +d(X_n,Y_n)  \rightarrow 0,
\end{align}
so $X_n \overset{d}{\rightarrow}X_\infty^+ -X_\infty^-$.$\hspace{2cm}\square$

Why does $d(X_n,Y_n) \rightarrow 0$ follow from the fact that $X_n$'s are Cauchy?

It does not, the proof is wrong.

Actually this proof does not work, as I found out after the helpful comment by @温泽海
$d(X_n, Y_n) \rightarrow 0$ does not follow from $X_n$ being Cauchy. In fact, the issue is with the premise of the proof, namely that $X_n \rightarrow^d \lim\inf X_n$. I should have realised this because constructing a counterexample is easy: let $([0,1],\mathcal{B}([0,1]), \lambda)$ be the probability space and let $X_n$ be the sequence
\begin{align}
X_1 &= 1 - \chi_{[0,1/2]} \\ 
X_2 &= 1- \chi_{[1/2,1]} \\
X_3 &= 1 - \chi_{[0,1/3]}\\
X_4 &= 1- \chi_{[1/3,2/3]}, \\
\end{align}
etc. Here $\chi_A$ is the indicator function of $A$. Then $X_n \rightarrow 1$ in probability and hence in $d( \cdot, \cdot)$, but $\inf_{k\geq n}X_n(\omega) =0$ for all $\omega, n$. A similar counterexample shows that the limiting random variables is not always $\lim\sup X_n$.
This question is Exercise 2.3.7 in Probability: Theory and Examples (5th Edition) by Durrettt. I have since found a correct proof of this result here.
